# A tag framework

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framework) means… um, as far as I can tell, that the software allows one to do stuff in it. It seems to be mainly about libraries, sometimes about tools to use during development, sometimes about tools that aren't about development. There isn't a meaningful way in which questions tagged [framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framework) are about *frameworks* — the tag might as well be called “stuff”.

Should we:

- Just burninate [framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framework)?
- Synonymize it to [software-development](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development) (not completely correct, but close), after a bit of cleanup?
- Retag as applicable, either removing it or changing it to “*something*-framework” on those questions that are in a community where the word “framework” has a specific meaning?

Comment: I see it more used as "something you can hang code on", which is slightly better than "stuff" but not much.

Comment: Additionally to what @Undo correctly pointed out, a framework is always a "collection of resources" – as opposed to "combining different resources yourself" (in the hope they work together). And if you check the [Wikipedia ambiguition page on Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framework), it's not restricted to development either (e.g. Application framework, Multimedia framework).

Answer (score 3):

A Framework is more than just a library, although most frameworks consist of some libraries themselves.

Frameworks are explicitly different from [software-development](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/software-development) as some programming languages don't have (m/any) frameworks to pick from in the first place, and software development doesn't require frameworks.

I recommend we retag the questions to [php-framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php-framework), [python-framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-framework) etc. and then blacklist [framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framework) to keep in from reappearing (with the note to use the language specific tag).

The idea behind this is that there are most likely no experts in frameworks in general, but there are php-framework experts as there are java-framework experts. I would add [java-framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/java-framework) to my favorites, but not [php-framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/php-framework) or [framework](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/framework).

The tag-wiki of the new tags should be:

> A framework is a collection of common functions, that enable the programmer in a consistent way, to have common tasks handled automatically.

In my area of work frameworks are so important and distinct that I usually see them in job-ads and can tell what the project is about by the frameworks they use.
Unfortunately some people don't separate their use of framework and library consistently, but that shouldn't stop us from doing it.

Comment: I agree with everything Angelo says here, including his reasoning for his retag proposal.